# Navigate to another page passing variables

Tags: react-native

I'm very new to React Native. I've got the following page which loads dates and results from a database, all displaying ok:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import Colors from "../../../res/Colors/Colors";
import { s, scale } from "react-native-size-matters";
import Axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";
import { SafeAreaView} from "react-navigation";


export default function HistoryScreen({ navigation }) {
  
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [Star, setStar] = useState(null);

  const [people, setPeople] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    _getHistory();
  }, []);

  const expandMonth  = (month,year) => {
    console.log(month);
    console.log(year);
  }



  const _getHistory = async () => {
    let star = await AsyncStorage.getItem("star");
    star = JSON.parse(star);
    setStar(star);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("StarID", star.StarID);
    Axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "**API URL**",
      data: formData,
      //headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
        var responseBody = response.data.detail;
        setPeople(responseBody);
        setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log({ error });
    });
  };

  if (loading)
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,

        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGrey,
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 40 : 40,
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
      }}
    >

    <Text style={styles.headerText}>History</Text>

    <FlatList
      //keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      data={people}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            expandMonth(item.Month,item.Year)
            navigation.navigate("HistoryMonthScreen", {
            Month: item.Month,
            Year: item.Year
            });
        }}
        style={styles.month}>
        <Text style={styles.monthname}>{moment(item.Month, 'M').format('MMMM')} {item.Year}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.monthcount}>{item.Count} Bookings</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />      


    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

However when clicking the `TouchableOpacity` object it doesn't navigate to the next page passing the year and month variables. I assume I need to call some form of navigation to it, however everything I have tried has resulted in error after error.

Answer (score 0):

For React Navigation 5 you have to use the `route` prop that is passed in alongside `navigation` for whatever screen you're navigating to.

Put the below code into `HistoryMonthScreen.js`

```
const HistoryMonthScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    console.log(route.params.Month, route.params.Year);
    return <View />
}
```

**Edit**: For context:

I'm going off what you have here

```
navigation.navigate("HistoryMonthScreen", {
            Month: item.Month,
            Year: item.Year
            });
```

So I'm assuming you have some React Navigator somewhere that looks like this:

```
const AppNavigator5 = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HistoryScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          animationEnabled: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HistoryScreen"
          component={HistoryScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HistoryMonthScreen"
          component={HistoryMonthScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Egg" component={Egg} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

You put the code with `route` and `navigation` inside that `HistoryMonthScreen` component. You can pass different params into `route.params` every time, you don't have to change HistoryMonthScreen.

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put that and how would I tell route what page it is meant to open whilst sending the params to? It will always be the same page just with different parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure if your HistoryMonthScreen and HistoryScreen are the same, but assuming you wrote them similarly, you replace `export default function HistoryScreen({ navigation }) {` with `export default function HistoryScreen({route, navigation}){` and then access Month and Year as shown above

Comment: HistoryMonthScreen is basically a clone with a breakdown. They are different files though `HistoryMonth.js` and `HistoryMonthScreen.js`. Apologies for my ignorance, I'm a web dev but trying to improve an app I had built.

Comment: no worries, in that case check my edit. It should be more clear now

Comment: I stole that `navigate.navigate.etc` from another page the developer made. `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate("VideoScreen", { Title: title });` however it didn't work with this.props. so I removed it. AppNavigator.js does have this `import VideoScreen from "../Screens/AppScreens/VideoScreen";
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  VideoScreen: VideoScreen,
});`

Comment: Adding ` HistoryMonthScreen: HistoryMonthScreen` to AppNavigator.js seems to have done the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Although, I'm now missing the main navigation. Home is called as follows: `Home: { screen: BottomTabNavigator }` but video screen: `VideoScreen: VideoScreen` on video screen there is not meant to be a navigation, however I would like there to be a navigation bar on HistoryMonthScreen. `HistoryMonthScreen: { screen: BottomTabNavigator }` Just goes back to the homescreen though.